# How to pass data through ng-content?

Tags: html, angular, transclusion, angular2-ngcontent

My goal is to select a piece of HTML in component 2 which should render HTML with data from component 1.

This is the demo pseudo code of my aproach:

**Component 1**

```
<div>     
  <ng-content select="[item-template]; context: { $implicit: data}"></ng-content>
</div>
```

**Component 2**

```
<app-component-1>
  <ng-template item-template let-data>
     <div>{{data.prop1}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</app-component-1>
```

Hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for `ngTemplateOutlet`

Comment: @yurzui I tried that and got error. Correct me if i am wrong please but I think`ngTemplateOutlet` is meant for HTML templates in same component.

Comment: What is the problem you were **originally** trying to solve with this *solution* that doesn't work for you.

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/eJ69MbIMWDwd3aMBsJ0p?open=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Reactgular I want to create a reusable component to list items and i would like the client of the component to decide the way items are displayed

Comment: Nothing special being asked here. Just pass the component a template as an input binding. `<app-component [ref]="example"></app-component><ng-template #example></ng-template>`. It has *nothing* to do with `<ng-content>`

Comment: @Reactgular That solution does not pass dynamic data from component 1 to component 2

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the working demo. Would that work for multiple `ngTemplateOutlet` with different `template`?